# How do you send a complex object with an ajax post method to c# controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm trying to send a complex javascript object to a mvc controller post method.
I receive a BadRequest response every time I run the method. It won't let me debug with visual studio, only with the web developer tools. I checked with fiddler to see that my JSON object seems to be in the same order as the View Model. Could anybody please help me with this?
I am using Asp.Net Core 1.0. Please let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Here's is my view model:

```
public class RouteViewModel
    {
        public RouteViewModel() { }
        public List<CheckpointViewModel> Checkpoints { get; set; }
        public int TotalDistance { get; set; }
    } 
 public class CheckpointViewModel
    {
        public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
        public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
    }
```

The logic to compile the object is as follows:

```
function createObject() {
    var routeModel = { Checkpoints: [] ,TotalDistance:totalDistance};
    for (var i = 0; i < markersOrders.length; i++) {
        var latlng = markersOrders[i].getPosition();
        var Checkpoint = {
            'Latitude': latlng.lat(),
            'Longitude': latlng.lng()
        };
        routeModel.Checkpoints.push(Checkpoint);
    }
    return JSON.stringify(routeModel);
}
```

Here's my ajax method:

```
function saveRoute() {
    var apiUrl = location.origin + "/map/AddRoute";
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: apiUrl,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: (createObject())
    }).done(function (msg) {
        alert("Data saved: " + msg);
    }).error(function(msg){alert("Error: "+ msg)});
}
```

The controller that is receiving the post is as follows:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult AddRoute([FromBody]RouteViewModel route)
        {
            RouteViewModel newRoute = route;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.AddRoute(newRoute.Checkpoints, newRoute.TotalDistance);
                _context.SaveRoute();
                return RedirectToAction("SavedRoutes");
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
        }
```

Here is my RAW Post:

```
POST https://localhost:44343/map/AddRoute HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44343
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 290
Accept: */*
Origin: https://localhost:44343
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: https://localhost:44343/Map/Map
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.4IsE6XVGxQo=CfDJ8HmVr1mwBStLrOG_4RXM-sje_SmjZYd-GboPG5E19rchqlC61XsNEwa7yOgIySC-U63iTH6cD0ggwqwmwdPJOibPKrxlctls_a_b3wmPvai80vYUx6j0Lckfn24GBf7X_xZhAl3eac892j7YDJWa9Oc; .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8HmVr1mwBStLrOG_4RXM-shK66Uthf3kfJJezCs7HCTztr-seJHxVj8l5MS66u4EWd72NEXUjebAIfHIxFZvHjZzjiQSVfLCxdHnmcsbYWXgGAmaA_sBjdimNQXnPAC-NMtp_fDeTCPJEoB1lBy1hl-GFQaAJdRzVrcc7OchWTSBVZ9jdHmm0htNyChcJ8BUCczH8FhVnPeFzlCM_reR8u2vsQrOxY_ZmczdUQ_mqCmTVLGDdRRJwHLhuafrZ2mmAXq1iDzQhprtv98qAx2zM4TSoAOBKoeALq_Oa2n1SDvFMMtGseDB1mLsj-LkPlKhcCmtB14kwDRctvOtxOqCbQTfFjhLlc5405_dccQjWJ3mITtn1ss3x1aHUP-pHHzFX9ZhusQ1-IqV4pPDs12c1q2B5Uz0qEOHaUByVEE5bKpzklTT2kxNW1V81aGMMmwbi9zFkuh9nUFnQmGCqf5VXSx-FTm-UDWZgyMnK0JpG7K4cpiSeycv9sOeP1qUlz-P28RXLhCvqYAX3FIccRfoQMf63tU5OfVhu1bhRdV_NQALhBpku9nrxFyxxECe5WRc4It-kCLiaOQBlYa9bewb80QiWIS-wHNDY5vVcdAkd2D5

{"Checkpoints":[{"Latitude":-34.004057732693184,"Longitude":25.649633891880512},{"Latitude":-34.00313273259371,"Longitude":25.65392542630434},{"Latitude":-34.001425013635725,"Longitude":25.653367526829243},{"Latitude":-34.00019756942711,"Longitude":25.650320537388325}],"TotalDistance":919}
```

As advised by @[Kiran Challa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1184056/kiran-challa) I collected my modelstate errors in the controller and wrote it to Output window like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult AddRoute([FromBody]RouteViewModel route)
        {
            RouteViewModel newRoute = route;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.AddRoute(newRoute.Checkpoints, newRoute.TotalDistance);
                _context.SaveRoute();
                return RedirectToAction("SavedRoutes");
            }
            else
            {
                //Getting errors
                var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
                Debug.WriteLine("Errors found: "+ errors+"\nEnd Errors found");
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
        }
```

In my output window when I trigger the controller, all I receive is this:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The required antiforgery header value "RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.<ValidateRequestAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.<OnAuthorizationAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Warning: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult:Information: Executing HttpStatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 400
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 37.4837ms 400
```

Comment: Could you share how your request json data looks like over the wire?

Comment: I believe there is no need for `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: I added the RAW fiddler Post data. Do I need to add anything else? I am not that familiar with fiddler..

Comment: @erdinger does it make a difference to it not working?

Comment: Try couple of things: 1. What does the ModelState say? Does it show any errors? 2. Enable logging(ex: console) and see if there are any errors logged

Comment: @KiranChalla I tried it and found out I apparently need to add a required antiforgery header value called 'RequestVerificationToken'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out where I went wrong. I either needed to send the required Verification Token along with the ajax post method or take away '[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]' in my controller. I went for the latter since security is not my current objective. Thanks for the suggestion @[KiranChalla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1184056/kiran-challa) –

Answer (score 1):

try having your createObject() return this:

```
function createObject() {
    var routeModel = { Checkpoints: [] ,TotalDistance:totalDistance};
    for (var i = 0; i < markersOrders.length; i++) {
        var latlng = markersOrders[i].getPosition();
        var Checkpoint = {
            'Latitude': latlng.lat(),
            'Longitude': latlng.lng()
        };
        routeModel.Checkpoints.push(Checkpoint);
    }
    return JSON.stringify({route: routeModel});
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this. It encapsulates the checkpoints array and integer in an objects and that's cool and all but nothing has changed in the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
  [HttpPost]        
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]  
     public ActionResult AddRoute(RouteViewModel route)  
    {  
        RouteViewModel newRoute = route;  
        if (ModelState.IsValid)  
        {  
            _context.AddRoute(newRoute.Checkpoints, newRoute.TotalDistance);  
            _context.SaveRoute();  
            return RedirectToAction("SavedRoutes");  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            return BadRequest(ModelState);  
        }  
    }
```

[image: worked out image]

Comment: i changed   **public IActionResult AddRoute([FromBody]RouteViewModel route) **  to public ActionResult AddRoute(RouteViewModel route)

Comment: I tried this change but no result. I think ActionResult has access to the  same functions as its interface IActionResult.